# How should someone test a button that evokes `showSaveFilePicker` using Cypress?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, end-to-end, showsavefilepicker

I'm trying to test a web text editor that saves and opens files from the local system. I'm using Cypress v11.2.0 with Chrome v107.

The file operations use the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) through the [browser-fs-access](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/browser-fs-access) library.

I'm unable to test any of the file operations like save, for example. When the underline system function [showSaveFilePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showSaveFilePicker) is called, the test throws an error.

This is the test code:

```js
  it("'new' creates and links to an empty file", () => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.get("#new").click();
  });
```

Here is the error image:

[image: cypress error]

The operation is working fine in the app.

My question is: how should someone test a button that evokes `showSaveFilePicker` using Cypress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work with plugin library [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events)

```js
import 'cypress-real-events'

it("'new' creates and links to an empty file", () => {
  cy.visit('https://googlechromelabs.github.io/browser-fs-access/demo/');
  cy.contains("button", 'Save Image File')
    .realClick();
});
```

---

#### Stubbing

Although, the problem is what to do next? The test can't interact with the live popup.

I guess stub the call as per example here [Window confirm popup](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/9.7.0/recipes/window-confirm.html).

But that doesn't need `cypress-real-events`, since the dialog is not actually called.

```js
it("'new' creates and links to an empty file", () => {
  cy.visit('https://googlechromelabs.github.io/browser-fs-access/demo/');

  cy.window().then((win) =>
    cy.stub(win, 'showSaveFilePicker').as('showSaveFilePicker').returns(true),
  )

  cy.contains("button", 'Save Image File')
    .click();

  cy.get('@showSaveFilePicker')
    .should('have.been.calledOnce')
    .invoke('restore')
});
```

Comment: I hoped that after succeding in the button click, I could find a way to interact with the dialog. I thank you a lot for anticipating that and offering an approach.